# Como eu faço para alinhar o input com os botoes de - e +?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

```css
.counter svg {
  
  left: 14.78%;
  right: 82.29%;
  
  bottom: 45.02%;
  fill: #2f3676;
  
}

.counter input {
  left: 10.04%;
  right: 85.77%;
  bottom: 45.02%;
  background: #DDE3E9;
  border: 1px solid #2F3676;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 42px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"> <!--parâmetro obrigatório-->

<head>
 <title>Teste Frontend VAGAS.com</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body >
 <div class="box">
  <div class="header">
   <div class="title">Formulário<br />para compra de<br /><strong>Pacote de Stickers</strong></div>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
  <div class="form">
   <div class="space"></div>
   <div class="fieldset">
    <div class="label"><strong>Quais stickers:</strong></div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" /> React</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" /> Vue</div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" /> Angular</div>
   </div>
   <div class="space-md"></div>
   <div class="fieldset">
    <div class="label"><strong>Quantos stickers de cada?</strong> </div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="counter">
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42">
      <path d="M4.667 0A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 0 4.667v32.666A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 4.667 42h32.666A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 42 37.333V4.667A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 37.333 0H4.667zm28 23.333H9.333v-4.666h23.334v4.666z" /></svg>
     <input type="text"  placeholder="0"  />
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42">
      <path d="M4.667 42h32.666A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 42 37.333V4.667A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 37.333 0H4.667A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 0 4.667v32.666A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 4.667 42zm4.666-23.333h9.334V9.333h4.666v9.334h9.334v4.666h-9.334v9.334h-4.666v-9.334H9.333v-4.666z" /></svg>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="space-md"></div>
   <div class="fieldset">
    <div class="label"><strong>Observações:</strong></div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <textarea id="descricao" placeholder="Alguma dúvida? Recado?"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="space-md"></div>
   

   <footer>
    <div id="res"><strong>Formulário enviado com sucesso!</strong></div>
    <button onclick="enviar()">ENVIAR</button>
    
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer alinhar os itens verticalmente, recomendo usar o `display: flex` no elemento pai, já que alinhar verticalmente dentro de um elemento com `display: block` não é nada prático.

Apesar da dica, não sei explicar porque o seu layout ficou tão desalinhado. Parece ser relacionado ao `svg`, mas infelizmente eu não sei explicar a causa.

```css
.counter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.counter svg {
  left: 14.78%;
  right: 82.29%;
  
  bottom: 45.02%;
  fill: #2f3676;
}

.counter input {
  left: 10.04%;
  right: 85.77%;
  bottom: 45.02%;
  background: #DDE3E9;
  border: 1px solid #2F3676;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 42px;
  margin: 0 5px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<!--parâmetro obrigatório-->

<head>
  <title>Teste Frontend VAGAS.com</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="title">Formulário<br />para compra de<br /><strong>Pacote de Stickers</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="space"></div>
    <div class="form">
      <div class="space"></div>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="label"><strong>Quais stickers:</strong></div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" /> React</div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" /> Vue</div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" /> Angular</div>
      </div>
      <div class="space-md"></div>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="label"><strong>Quantos stickers de cada?</strong> </div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <div class="counter">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42">
            <path d="M4.667 0A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 0 4.667v32.666A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 4.667 42h32.666A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 42 37.333V4.667A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 37.333 0H4.667zm28 23.333H9.333v-4.666h23.334v4.666z" /></svg>
          <input type="text" placeholder="0" />
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="42" height="42">
            <path d="M4.667 42h32.666A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 42 37.333V4.667A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 37.333 0H4.667A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 0 4.667v32.666A4.668 4.668 0 0 0 4.667 42zm4.666-23.333h9.334V9.333h4.666v9.334h9.334v4.666h-9.334v9.334h-4.666v-9.334H9.333v-4.666z" /></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="space-md"></div>
      <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="label"><strong>Observações:</strong></div>
        <div class="space"></div>
        <textarea id="descricao" placeholder="Alguma dúvida? Recado?"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="space-md"></div>


      <footer>
        <div id="res"><strong>Formulário enviado com sucesso!</strong></div>
        <button onclick="enviar()">ENVIAR</button>

      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado fera.